# Why are the terms Implicit and Explicit used in CSS Grid for declared CSS properties?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I find the terms "Implicit" and "Explicit" confusing when it comes to CSS Grid.

Consider the following CSS:

```
#myDiv {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50px;
    grid-auto-rows: 50px 75px;
}
```

When this is applied to the following HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv">
     <div>1</div>
     <div>2</div>
     <div>3</div>
     <div>4</div>
     <div>5</div>
     <div>6</div>
     <div>7</div>
     <div>8</div>
</div>
```

In this example `grid-template-columns: 50px;` is said to be an "Explicit" definition. This makes sense because it's defined explicitly in the CSS.

However, `grid-auto-rows: 50px 75px` is said to be an "Implicit" definition. But why is this because that property is also defined in the CSS?

How can you tell the difference between an Implicit and Explicit property for properties that are defined in a CSS file?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/difference-explicit-implicit-grids/

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted when nobody has answered the question. It says in the linked answer below "implicit refers to the rows/columns *automatically generated* by the browsers.". However, nothing in the above is automatic. If you were to change the values in `grid-auto-rows: 50px 75px` to something other than 50px / 75px you'd get a different result. So it's not happening "automatically", the browser is rendering what has been defined in CSS, i.e. it's (explicitly) declared, which is hugely misleading.

Comment: Are you asking why they are used or are you asking what they mean? The body of your post seems to indicate you just don't understand what they mean, but the title you used explains why you are getting downvotes/close votes, because the question in the title is opinion-based.

Comment: @TylerH originally I was asking why those terms are used, because their meaning in English language is contrary to what they are doing here (see the example of `grid-auto-rows` which is said to be "Implicit" even though the values are explicitly delcared in the CSS, as with the other "Explicit" declaration, `grid-template-columns:`). Somebody even commented further down you could replace them with "X" and "Y". So the answer is they mean absolutely nothing and the terminology has been decided upon by some idiot who though using arbitrary terminology was a clever idea. Good to know that though!

Comment: *the terminology has been decided upon by some idiot who though using arbitrary terminology was a clever idea* --> if you already reached that conclusion then why asking a question and wasting our time? You are clearly not ready to accept anything other what you already have in mind. Plus the community is fine by that idiot terminology and we don't really need your thoughts.

Comment: @TemaniAfif when I asked the question I hadn't reached any conclusion - that's partly why I was asking, to clarify matters. The conclusion I've come to, ironically, is based on the information you and several others have provided. It's hard to come to any other conclusion when the terms used have no sensible meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that nothing is created by CSS alone. CSS generates boxes when it matches elements in the DOM document.

The difference between "explicit" and "implicit" is the former is defined *directly* and the latter *indirectly*.

When an element matches a rule with `display:grid`, a grid container box is created and the explicit grid is created. If there is a grid container at all, then the lines and tracks of the explicit grid exist, regardless of what that DOM element contains. That grid has been *directly* defined to exist, simply by the presence of a grid container element.

In contrast, the implicit grid is the result of grid tracks being needed to be created to house grid *items* that don't, for whatever reason, fit in the explicit grid. Their presence is *indirectly* defined, and only exist if there are DOM elements that match rules which create those non-fitting grid items.